# JavaScript: Address Full minimum fields for Reporting

Tags: javascript, c#, logic

I have following 6 fields for address on my from

1. Address_Line1
2. Address_Line2
3. Address_Line3
4. Address_City
5. Address_Country
6. Address_PostCode

Now, none of the fields are mandate so created following new fields

named Alt_Address__1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6 (Not visible on the form) But

OnSave (Using JavaSCript)

Each of the above 6 invoice address fields will be considered, in this order - Street 1, Street 2, Street 3, City, County, Post Code.

The first populated field will be saved into Alt_Invoice_Address_1
The second populated field will be saved into Alt_Invoice_Address 2
and so on through the 6 fields.

I am unable to come up with a smart logic for this, Any suggestion on how can I write JavaScript Function to implement above requirements

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is after collecting all of your field datas in a single object like this:

```
let formObject = {
    "Street1": "manchester",
    "Street2": "123 road",
    "Street3": "something something",
    "City": "NY"
    "Country": "USA"
    "Postcode": "5165812168452"
}
```

You first extract all of your object's properties values by using the [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) function and store it in a new var.

The next step is by using the [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) function to iterate through each value and store them in a object with the appropriate property.

Since your property name are all the same (Alt_Invoice_Address) with only the number that increment, you can add the index parameter in your forEach function to manually create your property.

Here is an example:

```
let newFormObject = {};
let formValues = Object.values(formObject);
formValues.forEach((value, index)=>{
    let newPropertyName = "Alt_Invoice_Address_" + index;
    newFormObject[newPropertyName] = value;
});
```

Now you have your new object with all of the Alt_Address fields completed with populated field values.
Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks @Billy, will it work for below scenario like if Add line 2 is blank, Populate line 3 value into Alt_Address_2?

Comment: No it will not work, in fact it will create an object with the same number of property as the formObject, it doesn't check if the fields are not empty. So the Alt_Address_2 property will have an empty string as a value ("").
However this scenario can easily be cover by using the Array.prototype.filter() function.
In that scenario you filter the formValues var in order to only keep the non empty value, you code it like this: `formValues = formValues.filter(value => value != "")`.
Note that filter function make a shallow copy so that why I assigned it to formValues